# libgdx - creating a ninepatch

Tags: java, android, libgdx, nine-patch

I was reading from
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches

My image
[image]

```
toast_patch = new NinePatch(texture, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Output:

[image]

I'm only getting the edges..
(ignore the text)
What should I do?

Comment: Can you add a photo of that image while on 9patch? Or a photo of how you did it on 9patch.

Comment: @GreenFox that is just a texture, it doesn't have 9 patch in it.

Comment: I think you should maybe used a nine patch image. Its much easier. Just a suggestion. See my answer.

Comment: How big is your original texture?  20x20?

Comment: @P.T.yes. I've also tried with 4 16 4 16 as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the full width of the texture for the 'corners' so there are no pixels left to stretch through the edges or "middle" of the button.  A "nine patch" should have nine patches.  You've divvied the texture up into four pieces (the four corners), leaving no texture data for the other five parts.  Try:

```
toast_patch = new NinePatch(texture, 7, 7, 7, 7);
```

(Or anything that doesn't sum to 20 along one axis.  The first argument is the number of left-edge pixels, the second is the number of right-edge pixels, implicitly any remaining pixels are used for the 'middle' section.  Similarly for the top and bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this picture as a guide. I used your image on your question.

[image]

Comment: You mean to change the paramenters with 4 18 4 18 ?

Comment: I know this tool bro, but how to add the nine patch with libgdx ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   graySkin = new Skin()
   grayAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/gray.pack"));
   grayAtlas.createPatch("patch");
   graySkin.addRegions(grayAtlas);
   grayButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
   grayButtonStyle.font = fontB44;
   grayButtonStyle.up = graySkin.getDrawable("patch");

    //gray.pack
    gray.9.png
    format: RGBA8888
    filter: Nearest,Nearest
    repeat: none
    patch
      rotate: false
      xy: 1, 1
      size: 100, 100
      split: 17, 17, 19, 19
      orig: 100, 100
      offset: 0, 0
      index: -1
```

[my gray button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Ut2.png)